# How to copy a string into a char array in C++ without going over the buffer

Tags: c++, string, g++, char

I want to copy a string into a char array, and not overrun the buffer.

So if I have a char array of size 5, then I want to copy a maximum of 5 bytes from a string into it.

what's the code to do that?

Comment: std::string, don't know of any other kinds of strings.

Comment: There are character strings, a handful of more or less well known library strings and an uncounted number of home grown implementations.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First of all, [`strncpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncpy) is almost certainly *not* what you want. `strncpy` was designed for a fairly specific purpose. It's in the standard library almost exclusively because it already exists, not because it's generally useful.

Probably the simplest way to do what you want is with something like:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%.4s", your_string.c_str());
```

Unlike `strncpy`, this guarantees that the result will be NUL terminated, but does not fill in extra data in the target if the source is shorter than specified (though the latter isn't a major issue when the target length is 5).

Comment: +1 for unique answer. But, isn't this a lot of unnecessary overhead relative to `strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), 4); buffer[4] = '\0';`?

Comment: @academicRobot: Have you tested it, or noticed the difference? :) I'd prefer the `sprintf` solution, it's a bit more straightforward. Only when performance is lacking would I profile, maybe find this to be a problem, test it with `strncpy`, and maybe find it works better.

Comment: Prefer the safe version, `snprintf`, which lets you specify the target buffer size.

Comment: Or get a copy of strlcpy and use that. It guarantees NULL termination.

Comment: @academicRobot: In general case whether `strncpy` is faster or slower will depend on the relative sizes of the source string and the target buffer. Since `strncpy` does lots of wasted work in case of a large buffer, in general case misused `strncpy` is not only *slower*, but *catastropically slower*, orders of magnitude slower. The only thing that saves the day in this example is unrealistically small target buffer (only 5 chars).

Comment: It guarantees null termination, actually protects against buffer overruns, which is what this question is about, *and* doesn't run the risk of mangling the format string.  `sprintf` is about the worst possible solution to this problem.

Comment: I forgot `%.4s` works that way, so `sprintf` isn't the worst possible solution.  But that typo does illustrate why a more expressive solution should be preferred.

Comment: @jweyrich: since we're specifying only one "conversion", and specifying the maximum size for it, `snprintf` provides no advantage in this case.

Comment: -1: For the use of `sprintf` instead of `snprintf`. That's basically a license to buffer overrun.

Comment: @NicolBolas: This predates C++11, so `snprintf` was not part of C++ at the time. Even so, specifying the precision as done here limits the amount of data that can be written to the buffer, preventing buffer overruns (short of your specifying a size larger than the buffer -- and if you do that, `snprintf` won't prevent a buffer overrun either.

Comment: What makes you say that strncpy is not what the OP want? It appears to me that the "fairly specific purpose" it was designed for is *exactly* what the OP wants to do: Copy a sequence of characters with the explicit requirement of respecting the destination size.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: As pointed out in the answer, if you use `strncpy`, and the buffer is smaller than the input string, the result is *not* a string. You no longer have a nul terminator. Almost nobody ever actually wants that, and the question doesn't say so either.

Comment: That is correct; as always one must take care to terminate one's C strings. One can argue that not terminating the destination in the overflow case is a deplorable flaw in strncpy(), which was conceived to do *one job* (copy a C string, overflow-safe); the alternative, namely copying one char less than perhaps expected, would be less harmful. But still I think this function, however flawed, is exactly the tool for the job. It's just important to terminate the string.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: I'm amazed at the idea that anybody could think it's the right tool for the job when it doesn't actually do the job. I'm reasonably certain that the actual job for which `strncpy` was designed was copying a file name into an inode. It's perfect for that task, and utterly terrible for anything else.

Answer (score 57):

This is exactly what `std::string`'s copy function does.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    char test[5];
    std::string str( "Hello, world" );

    str.copy(test, 5);

    std::cout.write(test, 5);
    std::cout.put('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

If you need null termination you should do something like this:

```
str.copy(test, 4);
test[4] = '\0';
```

Comment: nice solution but not nowadays no longer free of warnings: `warning C4996: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::copy': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'`

Comment: @PaulWilliams that is stated in the last part of the answer.

Comment: The null termination should come right after the end of the copy, not at the end of the copied buffer. If the destination buffer already had content you'll have garbage in the output string.

Comment: The generalized way to terminate the chat buffer is

```
const size_t LEN = 5;
char test[LEN];
size_t len = str.copy(test, LEN-1);
test[len] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 8):

Use function <del>[`strlcpy`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/strlcpy)</del><sup>broken link, and material not found on destination site</sup> if your implementation provides one (the function is not in the standard C library), yet it is rather widely accepted as a de-facto standard name for a "safe" limited-length copying function for zero-terminated strings.

If your implementation does not provide `strlcpy` function, implement one yourself. For example, something like this might work for you

```
char *my_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n)
{
  assert(dst != NULL && src != NULL);

  if (n > 0)
  {
    char *pd;
    const char *ps;

    for (--n, pd = dst, ps = src; n > 0 && *ps != '\0'; --n, ++pd, ++ps)
      *pd = *ps;

    *pd = '\0';
  }

  return dst;
}
```

(Actually, the de-facto accepted `strlcpy` returns `size_t`, so you might prefer to implement the accepted specification instead of what I did above).

Beware of the answers that recommend using [`strncpy`](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/string/strncpy) for that purpose. `strncpy` is not a safe limited-length string copying function and is not supposed to be used for that purpose. While you can force `strncpy` to "work" for that purpose, it is still akin to driving woodscrews with a hammer.

Comment: The limitation with this being that in some cases you should detect that there was a buffer overflow. It would be more interesting to return the copy size instead of dst which is already known. In that case one can then handle the error when copy_size > n or know how much of the buffer is used up.

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Thought I would try to tie together some of the answers, answers which have convinced me that my own original knee-jerk strncpy response was poor.

First, as AndreyT noted in the comments to this question, truncation methods (snprintf, strlcpy, and strncpy) are often not a good solution. Its often better to check the size of the string `string.size()` against the buffer length and return/throw an error or resize the buffer.

If truncation is OK in your situation, IMHO, [strlcpy](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strlcpy) is the best solution, being the fastest/least overhead method that ensures null termination.  Unfortunately, its not in many/all standard distributions and so is not portable.  If you are doing a lot of these, it maybe worth providing your own implementation, AndreyT gave an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889421/how-to-copy-a-string-into-a-char-array-in-c-without-going-over-the-buffer/2889522#2889522).  It runs in O(*result length*).  Also the reference specification returns the number of bytes copied, which can assist in detecting if the source was truncated.

Other good solutions are [sprintf](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/sprintf) and [snprintf](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/c/io/snprintf).  They are standard, and so are portable and provide a safe null terminated result.  They have more overhead than strlcpy (parsing the format string specifier and variable argument list), but unless you are doing a lot of these you probably won't notice the difference.  It also runs in O(*result length*).  snprintf is always safe and that sprintf may overflow if you get the format specifier wrong (as other have noted, format string should be `"%.<N>s"` not `"%<N>s"`).  These methods also return the number of bytes copied.

A special case solution is [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/).  It runs in O(*buffer length*), because if it reaches the end of the src it zeros out the remainder of the buffer.  Only useful if you need to zero the tail of the buffer or are confident that destination and source string lengths are the same.  Also note that it is not safe in that it doesn't necessarily null terminate the string.  If the source is truncated, then null will not be appended, so call in sequence with a null assignment to ensure null termination: `strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), BUFFER_LAST); buffer[BUFFER_LAST] = '\0';`

Comment: @academicRobot: In general case whether `strncpy` is faster or slower will depend on the relative sizes of the source string and the target buffer. Since `strncpy` does lots of wasted work in case of a large buffer, in general case misused `strncpy` is not only slower, but *catastropically slower*, orders of magnitude slower. The only thing that saves the day in this example is unrealistically small target buffer (only 5 chars).

Comment: @academicRobot: You also skewed the test results by insisting on a source string that is known to be longer than the buffer. Testing for such string alone is absolutely meaningless.

Comment: Finally, your conclusion is totally bogus. `sprintf`/`snprintf` is indeed not the most efficient function for obvious reasons. But that only means that one has to prefer using a `strlcpy`-like function, not the virtually useless `strncpy`. Finally, the importance of performance in a truncation-enabled string copying context is another issue. String truncation seen as something acceptable usually indicated user-interface application. Who needs performance in user interface?

Comment: @AndreyT Thank you sir, may I please have another! :) You are right on every point, except I won't concede the last (just for user interfaces, really?!?!).  But using an strlcpy like function is probably the best option.

Comment: Well, think of it: you copy a string and you agree to lose a portion of that string (if it's too long). I.e. the data you copy gets distorted/corrupted/damaged/truncated (choose to your taste). In which context can this be acceptable? They only context I can come up with is a user-interface one: you tell user something very long and that something doesn't suffer much if you cut it a bit (like a list of errors, for example, when just the first one is enough). Can you come up with another context when the truncated data is OK?

Comment: @AndreyT Asking for another is just an American idiom.  See Animal House (1978).

Comment: It is not about your "asking for another" reference. It is about your "user interfaces" remark.

Comment: @AndreyT ...but since you gave it to me anyway, I'd say you're right in the sense that in some situations using truncation methods smells like a bad choice.  But I wouldn't be so grandiose as to say the only situation where it is appropriate is UI.

Answer (score 3):

Some nice libc versions provide non-standard but great replacement for `strcpy(3)`/`strncpy(3)` - [`strlcpy(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strlcpy/).

If yours doesn't, the source code is freely available [here](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/lib/libc/string/strlcpy.c) from the [OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org) repository.

Answer (score 3):

```
void stringChange(string var){

    char strArray[100];
    strcpy(strArray, var.c_str()); 

}
```

I guess this should work. it'll copy form string to an char array.

Answer (score 2):

i think  snprintf()  is much safe and simlest

```
snprintf ( buffer, 100, "The half of %d is %d", 60, 60/2 );
```

null character is append it end automatically :)

Answer (score 2):

The most popular answer is fine but the null-termination is not generic. The generic way to null-terminate the char-buffer is:

```cpp
std::string aString = "foo";
const size_t BUF_LEN = 5;
char buf[BUF_LEN];
size_t len = aString.copy(buf, BUF_LEN-1); // leave one char for the null-termination
buf[len] = '\0';
```

`len` is the number of chars copied so it's between `0` and `BUF_LEN-1`.

Comment: This is actually better than the most popular answer, because this will do the proper thing in case the copied string is smaller than BUF_LEN.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string my_string("something");
char* my_char_array = new char[5];
strncpy(my_char_array, my_string.c_str(), 4);
my_char_array[4] = '\0'; // my_char_array contains "some"
```

With [`strncpy`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/), you can copy at most *n* characters from the source to the destination. However, note that if the source string is at most *n* chars long, the destination will not be null terminated; you must put the terminating null character into it yourself.

A char array with a length of 5 can contain at most a string of 4 characters, since the 5th must be the terminating null character. Hence in the above code, *n* = 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string str = "Your string";
char buffer[5];
strncpy(buffer, str.c_str(), sizeof(buffer)); 
buffer[sizeof(buffer)-1] = '\0';
```

The last line is required because strncpy isn't guaranteed to NUL terminate the string (there has been a discussion about the motivation yesterday).

If you used wide strings, instead of `sizeof(buffer)` you'd use `sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer)`, or, even better, a macro like

```
#define ARRSIZE(arr)    (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*(arr)))
/* ... */
buffer[ARRSIZE(buffer)-1]='\0';
```

Answer (score -1):

```
char mystring[101]; // a 100 character string plus terminator
char *any_input;
any_input = "Example";
iterate = 0;
while ( any_input[iterate] != '\0' && iterate < 100) {
    mystring[iterate] = any_input[iterate];
    iterate++;
}
mystring[iterate] = '\0';
```

This is the basic efficient design.

Answer (score -2):

If you always have a buffer of size 5, then you could do:

```
std::string s = "Your string";
char buffer[5]={s[0],s[1],s[2],s[3],'\0'};
```

Edit:
Of course, assuming that your std::string is large enough.

Comment: This does not scale at all to buffers of arbitrary size.

Comment: Right. That's why I wrote "always have a buffer of size 5".