# Given a starting and ending indices, how can I copy part of a string in C?

Tags: c, string, substring

In C, how can I copy a string with begin and end indices, so that the string will only be partially copied (from begin index to end index)?

This would be like 'C string copy' `strcpy`, but with a begin and an end index.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Have you checked [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)?

> char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num );

You must realize that *begin* and *end* actually defines a **num** of bytes to be copied from one place to another.

Comment: As I noted in a previous answer, there is almost no reasonable question to which `strncpy` is a good answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889421/how-to-copy-a-string-into-a-char-array-in-c-without-going-over-the-buffer/2889483#2889483

Answer (score 84):

Use [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy)

e.g.

```
strncpy(dest, src + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex);
```

This assumes you've

1. Validated that `dest` is large enough.
2. `endIndex` is greater than `beginIndex`
3. `beginIndex` is less than `strlen(src)`
4. `endIndex` is less than `strlen(src)`

Comment: To get `abc` from `"abc"`, you'd do: `strncpy(dest, src + 1, strlen(src) - 2);`. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 13):

Just use [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

If the destination isn't big enough, [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) won't null terminate. if the destination is huge compared to the source, [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) just fills the destination with nulls after the string. [strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) is pointless, and unsuitable for copying strings.

[strncpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) is like [memcpy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) except it fills the destination with nulls once it sees one in the source. It's absolutely useless for string operations. It's for fixed with 0 padded records.