# Can't copy a part of a string

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, digit, strncpy

I was wondering how I can copy a part of a string to another one, so I checked this web to see if I could get an answer, and I did: [How can I copy part of another string in C, given a starting and ending index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205195/how-can-i-copy-part-of-another-string-in-c-given-a-starting-and-ending-index)

However, when I use this

```
strncpy(dest, src + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex);
```

on my code, it does not work. Why? I think I have added  the indexs properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
#define MAX 15

int main()
{
    int j=0;
    int i;
    char RPNarray[MAX];
    printf("Enter the RPN");
    fgets(RPNarray,MAX,stdin);
    int t=strlen(RPNarray);
    double RPN[t][2];

    for(i=0;i<=t;i++)
    {
        if(isspace(RPNarray[i]))
        {
            i=i+1;
        }
        else if (isdigit(RPNarray[i]))
        {
            int q,h;
            q=i;
            for (h=i;isdigit(RPNarray[h]);h++)
            {
                h=h+1;
            }
            int r;
            double u;
            r=h-q;
            char number[r];
            printf("%s ", RPNarray);
            strncpy(number,RPNarray + q,h - q);
            printf ("%s\n",number);
            u=atof(number);
            printf("%lf.\n",u);
            RPN[j][0]=0;
            RPN[j][1]=u;
            i=i+1;
            j=j+1;
        }
    }
    int b;
    for (b=0;b<=j;b++)
    {
        printf("%lf %lf \n",RPN[b][0],RPN[b][1]);
    }
}
```

`r` is the number of digits of the number, `q` the position of the first digit of the number and h the first position after the number that is not a number.

This program should print the RPN matrix as the code says.

```
 (0,(first number we introduce via stdin)
 (0,(second number we introduce via stdin)
 (0,(third number we introduce via stdin)
```

I have also added more prints to see where is the problem, and as you can see, the second print is not printed as it should.

If the input is:

```
56 6 
The output is:
56 6
 56OT?
56.000000.
vector 0.000000 56.000000 
vector 0.000000 0.000000
```

What can I do so the output is:

```
56 6
 56
56.000000.
56 6
 6
6.000000.
vector 0.000000 56.000000 
vector 0.000000 6.000000
```

Thank you

Comment: Please edit your post and fix the indention.

Comment: Learn how to use a debugger, and step through the code, line by line.

Comment: The loop ending conditions `<=` are suspicious. In the first one `t` is going past the length of the string. In the second one `b` is indexing an element of `RPN[b]` that has not been set at the current value of `j`,which was incremented after it was used.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code 2) variable names should indicate content or usage (or better, both) 3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: do not `#include` header files those content is not used.  I.E. do not include math.h

Comment: when writing code, use appropriate comments.  Comments should explain what the code is trying to do, or what has been accomplished or explain an algorithm,  not trivialities within the code

Comment: the call to `fgets()` will also input the trailing newline ('\n').   Usually the code should eliminate any trailing newline.  Note: the returned value from `fgets()` should be check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`

Comment: all the code seems to be trying to do is extract the first numeric sub string from the input and convert that to a integer. then place that integer into the `RPN[][]` array, which the code is using a very convoluted algorithm to perform.   However, the code does not properly handle a input with no embedded numeric string nor input with any alphabetic characters.  the posted code fails if the numeric sub string contains a decimal point `.`  Note: no need to extract the sub string, the `atof()` function does not care where the string is located

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just needed to `continue` instead of incrementing?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MAX 15

int main() {

    int j = 0;
    int i;
    char RPNarray[MAX];
    printf("Enter the RPN");
    fgets(RPNarray, MAX, stdin);
    int t = strlen(RPNarray);
    double RPN[t][2];

    for (i = 0; i <= t; i++) {
        if (isspace(RPNarray[i])) {
            continue;//i = i + 1;
        }
        else if (isdigit(RPNarray[i])) {
            int q, h;
            q = i;
            for (h = i; isdigit(RPNarray[h]); h++) {
                h = h + 1;
            }
            int r;
            double u;
            r = h - q;
            char number[r];
            printf("%s ", RPNarray);
            strncpy(number, RPNarray + q, h - q);
            printf("%s\n", number);
            u = atof(number);
            printf("%lf.\n", u);
            RPN[j][0] = 0;
            RPN[j][1] = u;
            i = i + 1;
            j = j + 1;
        }
    }
    int b;
    for (b = 0; b <= j; b++) {
        printf("%lf %lf \n", RPN[b][0], RPN[b][1]);
    }
}
```

Test

```
Debug/gnu
Enter the RPN56 6
56 6
 56
56.000000.
56 6
 6

6.000000.
0.000000 56.000000 
0.000000 6.000000 
0.000000 0.000000
```

It looks like the output you want. All I did was to change one statement.