# in C++ How to assign an element of an array of strings to an array of char?

Tags: c++

in c++ suppose I have:

```
string s[] = {"red","green","blue"} ;
char c[50] ;
```

I wanna make an assignment like this:

```
c = s[0] ;
```

how can I do it ???

Comment: `char c[50]` is not a pointer type, btw - think of it as the same thing as putting `char c0, c1, c2, c3, c4` - so you'll need to copy the `string`'s characters into `c` rather than merely assigning a pointer/reference **or** change `char c[50]` to a pointer or reference to a heap-allocated array.

Comment: That said, if you want to write C++ and not C, then use STL types like `std::vector` and `std::array` and avoid raw pointers and raw arrays.

Comment: `strncpy(c, s.c_str(), 50);` followed by `c[49] = '\0';` for robustness

Comment: As an aside, often you can make do with the c_str() function, for example if a legacy function expects a const char*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy a string into a char array in C++ without going over the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889421/how-to-copy-a-string-into-a-char-array-in-c-without-going-over-the-buffer)

Answer (score 0):

For whatever the purpose, consider if you can use `std::string` instead of a `char` array (re. array `c`).

If you still want to do it, you can use [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy) or [`memcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy):

```
const char *cstr = s[0].c_str();
size_t len = strlen(cstr);
size_t len_to_copy = len > sizeof c ? sizeof c : len;

memcpy(c, cstr, len_to_copy - 1);
c[len_to_copy - 1] = 0;
```

(Copying a byte less & terminating with null byte isn't necessary if 'c' doesn't need to be a C-string).

Note that this could truncate if `c` doesn't have any space. Perhaps `std::vector<char>` is better suited (depends on the use-case of course).

Comment: If the string is shorter than the array, it won't be null-terminated properly. Also you can copy one character less than `sizeof c`, if you're going to overwrite the last one with `0`.

Comment: Or a `std::string_view` for that matter

Answer (score 0):

I would use `std::copy`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string strings[] = {"string", "string2"};
  char s[10];
  std::copy(strings[0].begin(), strings[0].end(), s);
  std::cout << s; // outputs string
}
```

The advantage of using `std::copy` is its use of iterators.

Comment: This doesn't null-terminate the destination `char` array.

Comment: This may cause nasty errrors, if the input strings are longer than the buffers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `std::strncpy`. It will zero terminate your buffer and wont write out of bounds.

```
char c[50];
std::string test_string = "maybe longer than 50 chars";
std::strncpy(c, test_string.c_str(), sizeof(c));
```